# fbconnect OAuth2

Tags: playframework

This is the error message I get in my browser, I have added the jar files, and there is now no error in import!! but the error read like this

The file /app/controllers/FacebookLogin.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : play.modules.facebook.FbGraph cannot be resolved

In /app/controllers/FacebookLogin.java (around line 4)

```
 package controllers;

 import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

 import play.modules.facebook.FbGraph;

 import play.modules.facebook.FbGraphException;

 import play.mvc.Scope.Session;

 public class FacebookLogin{

 public static void facebookLogin() {
         try {
```

please help me out, I am trying to connect to facebook for more than week, I am really stuck.
Please help me with the controller class and view file.

thanks

Comment: Whatever Jar you put in lib folder of your project should be picked up directly by play. It requires a server restart though.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/play-fbgraph/wiki/GettingStarted) and it's going to work.

30 minutes maximum, really easy to do.

Comment: Hey Jean-Philippe, I am getting this error while implementing the code provided by the link you have given.

**The template tags/fbg/scriptAsync.html or tags/fbg/scriptAsync.tag does not exist.**

Can you please help me out!!!

I will really appreciate if you can completely giude me to do this stuff!!

Thanks!

Comment: You did not installed correctly the module.
Are you sure you correctly did :
- play install fbgraph-0.4
- edit dependencies.yml
- play dependencies
- play eclipsify
- reimport the projet into Eclipse

Comment: Hey Jean-Philippe, I am still trying this, and you have been great help to me. Now I have got the tag working, but I am now getting null pointer exception. `JsonObject profile = FbGraph.getObject("me"); // fetch the logged in user`
`String email = profile.get("email").getAsString(); // retrieve the email` please help me again, I am really appreciate your help  thank you

Comment: should I be using something other than **me** in FbGraph.getObject("me"). I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: Have you logged in Facebook using your new Login button before ? You must first login with this button. Facebook will ask you if you allow your app to access your FB informations. You must accept. Then the API will be able to access the FB informations.